# Windows - Is there any way to detect if a Remote Desktop Session window on my desktop was disconnected?

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-server-2019

I have multiple remote desktop sessions (RDP) to other servers running on my desktop. Occasionally, one will get booted either due to network problems or the RDP session being launched somewhere else that causes me to get booted.

Is there a way for me to detect that I have lost an RDP window programmatically? Is there a window handle I can query? I don't think the title of the window changes unfortunately. If there were a way to also close the existing window after some time limit of being disconnected, that would also work since I could detect the window missing.

Comment: If you're using a tool like RoyalTS, the application's log will tell you. Without using a wrapper around RDP like that, you'd have to build one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

mRemoteNG, you can configure logging settings to track RDP session events, including disconnections

Open mRemoteNG and select the connection you want to monitor.
Right-click on the connection and choose "Edit Connections."
In the Connection Properties window, go to the "Advanced" tab.
Under the "Security" section, check the box for "Logon and Logoff events."
Click "OK" to save your changes.

This will be logged to mremote.log